# SIGSEGV error in copy constructor of template class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, copy-constructor, template-classes

I am trying to test/debug a simple c++ code with template class and copy constructor. I define a vector class (user defined not STL) with 2 constructors one for initialization of vector elements and another for assigning values from an array. First I call the initialization constructor ,the code runs fine ,but when I call the constructor with a float array elements , the very first assignment statement hits SIGSEGV error , I have checked all values and addresses in debugger , no hints found. I give below the code ,I give below the sequence of calls and line details of error , from main vector() is called ,no issues , then  v1=inputf1; is invoked ,then the copy constructor vector(T1* t2) is invoked , there code hits SIGSEGV error at very first assignment stmt in the loop that is t[i]=t2[i]; ,please help understand, since the code is small you can as well try executing and let me know -Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int size = 4;

template <class T1>

class vector {
    
    T1* t;
    
public:
    
    vector() {
        
        t = new T1[size];
        
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            t[i] =0;
        
    }


    vector(T1* t2) {
                
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            t[i]=t2[i];//SIGSEGV error at this stmt//
        
        }
    
        
    T1 operator * (vector &va) {
        
        T1 sum=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            sum += this->t[i]*va.t[i];
            
        return sum;
                
    }
    
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    int ip;
    float ipf;
    
    float inputf1[4] = {1.2,2.3,3.4,4.5};
    vector<float> v1;
    v1=inputf1;
    float inputf2[4] = {5.6,6.7,7.8,8.9};
    vector<float> v3;
    v3=inputf2;
    
    int inputi1[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> v2;
    v2=inputi1;
    
    int inputi2[4] = {5,6,7,8};
    vector<int> v4;
    v4=inputi2;
    
    ip = v2*v4;
    ipf = v1*v3;
    
    cout<<"inner product of int vectors = "<< ip <<endl;
    
    cout<<"inner product of float vectors = "<< ipf <<endl;
    
     
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t` is not initialized in the `vector(T1* t2)` constructor prior to the assignment. Namig your class `vector` + `using namespace std` is a disaster waiting to happen. Same goes for `size` and `std::size`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not initializing `t` in `vector(T1 *t2)`.

In this case you could inherit the constructors like this:

```
vector(T1 *t2):vector() {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        t[i] = t2[i]; 
}
```

But where is `vector(T1 *t2)` called? In each assignment because there is not `operator` taking `T*`.

```
v1=inputf1
```

is rewritten as

```
v1.operator=(vector<float>(inputf1));
```

because the compiler found this implicit conversion to work. Of course neither `operator=` nor `vector(T* vals)` are implemented correctly, so it will fail somewhere.

Even if you fix the constructor, your code has errors because you did not implement the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) correctly.

## Notes

> copy constructor `vector(T1* t2)`

This is not a copy constructor, but an ordinary one. `vector(const vector<T1>&)` would be the copy ctor.

Consider making constructor with one argument `explicit`, this would forbid the implicit conversion.

At least directly initialize each member as a backup if you forget. `T* t=nullptr;`, this will make the code deterministically segfault. Better than nothing.

> I have checked all values and addresses in debugger , no hints found.

I find that dubious, what kind of debugger are you using? Because common ones will break on segfaults, give call stack, and allow inspecting of all variables. You would see `t` not being initialized there.

Your code is really unsafe, [do not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), you have clashes with `std::size` already and will have more if you `#include <vector>`. How does it compile for you? It does not for me.

I recommend to get a decent compiler, debugger, enable warnings `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and use sanitizers, they are really quick for tracking errors. Address sanitizer shows for example:

```
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fbd726014d0 (pc 0x000000401d0c bp 0x7ffe0c253230 sp 0x7ffe0c253210 T0)
==1==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
    #0 0x401d0c in vector<float>::vector(float*) /app/example.cpp:28
    #1 0x401615 in main /app/example.cpp:57
    #2 0x7fbd726490b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x240b2)
    #3 0x40114d in _start (/app/output.s+0x40114d)
```

Thus making the error clear.

Comment: Thanks Quimby  , just adding this one line vector(T1 *t2):vector()  helped and got the expected result ,btw I am using codelite IDE with MinGW which is a "decent" compiler for windows I believe.